# Draw a line to connect two cicrles

Tags: jquery

I have two div elements and style them like circles. Then I want to draw a line to connect these two circles by their closest points. My strategy is to find the center point of two div since the straight line that connect the two points will be the shortest path. Then draw a line based on two points that intersect with the line and the outline of the circles. I can conceptualize and visualize it, but I can put it to code. Help please!

```css
.c {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.c a {
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #06849b;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#c1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 5px;
}


#c1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1" class="c"><a href="#">Circle1</a></div>

<div id="c2" class="c"><a href="#">Circle2</a></div>
```

Comment: What information do you have about the circles? Do you already know their size, position, etc. or do you need to detect it?

Comment: I have to detect it myself.

Comment: Do you know the circle's ids? Also, how are they positioned - absolute, relative,fixed, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I should make it clearer. I have updated with my style. The circle will be position absolute and dynamic radius.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just rediscovered highschool math for this question.. :D

http://jsfiddle.net/r1qL55f7/2/

```
var circles = $('<div class="circle">'),
    cont = $('.cont'),
    n = 15;

//generate circles
while (n--) cont.append(circles.clone().text(n+1));
circles = $('.circle');

//position circles randomly
var w = cont.width(),
    h = cont.height();
circles.each(function(){
    $(this).css('top',h*Math.random()+'px');
    $(this).css('left',w*Math.random()+'px');
});


//generate lines
circles.each(function(i){
    var pos0 = $(this).position(),
        pos1 = (circles.eq(i+1)||{}).position();

    if (pos1==undefined) return;
    var x0 = pos0.left,
        y0 = pos0.top,
        x1 = pos1.left,
        y1 = pos1.top;
    line(x0, y0, x1, y1);
});


function line(x, y, x1, y1) {
    var l = $("<div class='line'>");
    //soh cah TOA and pythargoream theorem
    var w = circles.width()/2;
    l.css({
        top: y+w,
        left: x+w,
        width: Math.sqrt((x1-x)*(x1-x) + (y1 - y)*(y1 - y)),
        transform: 'rotate('+Math.atan2((y1-y),(x1-x))+'rad)'
    });
    cont.append(l);
}
```

About line:

line thickness is the height of div.

line's length is the width of div.

I set transform origin as left and center of the line.

Then set it's position to starting div.

then rotate it to x radians, luckly css rotate accept radians.

and luckly atan2 gives radian.

and for the takes care for signs which change depending on which quadrant your line is in. Math.atan only gives for quadrant 1 with which we are all so familiar with.

Comment: Thank you. Those highschool students are brilliant.

Comment: The provided fiddle dosn't work in Safari ... lines are placed outside the circles.

Comment: Try adding prefixfreejs and let me know

Answer (score 2):

I would use svg.

First add svg tag to the html:

```
<svg id="svg" height="100%" width="100%"></svg>
```

Then use jquery to calculate where the centers of the circles and draw a line between the two:

```
var c1 = $('#c1');
var c2 = $('#c2');

var newLineBeginX = c1.position().left + (c1.width() / 2);
var newLineBeginY = c1.position().top + (c1.height() / 2);

var newLineEndX = c2.position().left + (c2.width() / 2);
var newLineEndY = c2.position().top + (c2.height() / 2);

var line = "<line x1='"+newLineBeginX+"' y1='"+newLineBeginY+"' x2='"+newLineEndX+"' y2='"+newLineEndY+"' style='stroke:#06849b;stroke-width:2' />"
//var line = "<span class='line' style='height:"+lineSize+"px'></span>";
$("#svg").append(line);
$("body").html($("body").html());
```

My css:

```
#svg {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

For the complete picture, here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmnoohky/1/

If you need the text then you may need to tweak it a tiny bit so that the line doesn't cover the text.

Comment: I have another circle C3 that is center bottom of C1 and C2, how can I draw a line from the middle of both C1 and C2 to C3?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class='Circle' id='C1'></div>
<div class='Circle' id='C2'></div>
<div class='Line' id='L1'></div>
<button onclick='Circles.place(); return false;'>Place Circles</buton>
```

CSS:

```
.Circle {
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:50px;
    width:50px;height:50px;
    margin:-25px;/* make any position act as circle-center */
}
#C1 { background:#080; }
#C2 { background:#05A; }

.Line {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;/* Magic here */
    height:2px;
    background:#800;
}

button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    Circles.Elm = [$('#C1'),$('#C2'),$('#L1')];
    Circles.place();
});

var Circles = {
    Elm : [],
    Max : [300,200],
    pos1 : [],
    pos2 : [],
    place : function(){
        Circles.pos1 = [Math.round(Math.random()*(Circles.Max[0]-25)+25),Math.round(Math.random()*(Circles.Max[1]-25)+25)];
        Circles.pos2 = [Math.round(Math.random()*(Circles.Max[0]-25)+25),Math.round(Math.random()*(Circles.Max[1]-25)+25)];
        Circles.Elm[0].css('left',Circles.pos1[0]+'px').css('top',Circles.pos1[1]+'px');
        Circles.Elm[1].css('left',Circles.pos2[0]+'px').css('top',Circles.pos2[1]+'px');
        Circles.lineDraw();
    },
    lineDraw : function(){
        L = Math.sqrt(
            (Circles.pos1[0]-Circles.pos2[0])*(Circles.pos1[0]-Circles.pos2[0]) +
            (Circles.pos1[1]-Circles.pos2[1])*(Circles.pos1[1]-Circles.pos2[1]) );
        A = Math.atan2(Circles.pos2[1]-Circles.pos1[1],Circles.pos2[0]-Circles.pos1[0])*(180/Math.PI);
        Circles.Elm[2].css({
            'left':Circles.pos1[0]+'px',
            'top':Circles.pos1[1]+'px',
            'transform':'rotate('+A+'deg)',
            'width':L,
        });
    },
}
```